# How to use LoggingInteceptor in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to use `LoggingInterceptor` provided by Mule ESB. I assume the usage of this interceptor should be pretty straight forward, but somehow it's not working with the code that I'm using, is there something that I'm missing here?

```
<flow name="loggingInterceptor-demo">
    <logging-interceptor doc:name="Log interceptor" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <logging-interceptor doc:name="Log interceptor"/>
</flow>
```

As per the documentation *LoggingInterceptor is a simple interceptor that logs a message before and after the event processing.* but it's not logging anything in the console. What am I missing here.

Runtime version: 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that definition you quoted from the docs--so much stuff. If you haven't found docs about the [Advanced tab of the Java Component Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/java-component-reference#advanced-tab), it might hold a clue. Here are results of my novice approach using Studio to configure the interceptor you described.

```
    <flow name="myprojectFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component class="org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject" doc:name="Java">
        <logging-interceptor/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

If I use the custom-transformer (Java Transformer), I don't see a way to add the interceptor.